# Typescript named object destructuring

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to destruct object with custom variable names?

**TypeScript**:

```
const { top } = { top: 1000 };
```

**JavaScript**:

```
var top = { top: 1000 }.top;
```

*But I want something like shown bellow(does not work).*

**TypeScript**:

```
const { top as elementTop } = { top: 1000 };
```

**JavaScript**:

```
var elementTop = { top: 1000 }.top;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
const { top: elementTop } = { top: 1000 };
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names)

Comment: Great, thanks! Sometimes I have hard times finding stuff for TypeScript, but I constantly keep forgetting that thing I am searching for is probably ES6

Comment: @Clem yeah, a lot of times the MDN documentation can be of more use.

Answer (score 3):

This is an ES6 de-structuring when you need to assign to new variable names:

> var o = {p: 42, q: true};
>
> var {p: foo, q: bar} = o;

In your example, it will be:

```
const { top: elementTop } = { top: 1000 };
```

For additional details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Thanks! I accepted previous answer, as it was answered sooner. Is that ok?

Comment: Sure. Anything which solves your issue in best way should be accepted